# Computation of numerical integral involving convolution

Tags: r, statistics, maxima

I have to solve the following convolution related numerical integration problem in R or perhaps computer algebra system like Maxima.
**Integral[({k(y)-l(y)}^2)dy]**
where
 k(.) is the pdf of a standard normal distribution
l(y)=integral[k(z)*k(z+y)dz] (standard convolution)
z and y are scalars
The domain of y is -inf to +inf.
The integral in function l(.) is an indefinite integral. Do I need to add any additional assumption on z  to obtain this?
Thank you.

Comment: I think I figured this out. The key element is the convolution of two normal distribution is also a normal distribution  with means and variances added together. Thus l(y) is the pdf of a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 2. Now the whole integral reduces to (2-2^0.5)^2 * Integral[f(z)^2,-Inf,Inf] (which can be numerically computed in R . Please let me know if there is any fault with this logic.

Comment: I found a flaw in above logic in the step (2-2^0.5)^2 * Integral[f(z)^2,-Inf,Inf] . The integral has to be evaluated as it is. The simplification given here was not right. I will like to thank @rcs for making me think about this a bit more. Now my R output matches that of Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a symbolic solution from *Mathematica*:

[image: mathematica output]

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed the correct answer. Will try to convert it to Maxima code.

Answer (score 2):

R does not do symbolic integration, just numerical integration.  There is the Ryacas package which intefaces with Yacas, a symbolic math program that may help.

See the distr package for possible help with the convolution parts (it will do the convolutions, I just don't know if the result will be integrable symbolicly).

You can numerically integrate the convolutions from distr using the integrate function, but all the parameters need to be specified as numbers not variables.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful tip. I will check out Ryacas. +1 for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is the same problem solved with Maxima 5.26.0.

```
(%i2) k(u):=exp(-(1/2)*u^2)/sqrt(2*%pi) $
(%i3) integrate (k(x) * k(y + x), x, minf, inf);
(%o3) %e^-(y^2/4)/(2*sqrt(%pi))
(%i4) l(y) := ''%;
(%o4) l(y):=%e^-(y^2/4)/(2*sqrt(%pi))
(%i5) integrate ((k(y) - l(y))^2, y, minf, inf);
(%o5) ((sqrt(2)+2)*sqrt(3)-2^(5/2))/(4*sqrt(3)*sqrt(%pi))
(%i6) float (%);
(%o6) .02090706601281356
```

Sorry for the late reply. Leaving this here in case someone finds it by searching.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do something similar in matlab, where I convolute two random (Rayleigh distributed) variables. The result of fz_fun is equal to fy_fun, I don't know why. Maybe some here knows it?

```
sigma1 = 0.45;
sigma2 = 0.29;

fx_fun =@(x) [0*x(x<0) , (x(x>=0)./sigma1^2).*exp(-0.5*(x(x>=0)./sigma1).^2)];
fy_fun =@(y) [0*y(y<0) , (y(y>=0)./sigma2^2).*exp(-0.5*(y(y>=0)./sigma2).^2)];

% Rayleigh distribution of random var X,Y:
step = 0.1;
x= -2:step:3;
y= -2:step:3;

%% Convolution:
z= y;
fz = zeros(size(y));
for i = 1:length(y)
    fz_fun(i) = integral(@(z) fy_fun(y(i)).*fx_fun(z-y(i)),0,Inf); % probability density of random variable z= x+y   
end
```